# Multiple arguments for data in BOOST_PP_REPEAT

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

I want to use BOOST_PP_REPEAT(count, macro, data) and my macro looks like

`TEMPLATE (z, n, x, y)

BOOST_PP_REPEAT (5, TEMPLATE, 4, 5)`

It complains about BOOST_PP_REPEAT being passed 4 arguments while it only expects 3. Is there a way to pack two arguments into the "data" parameter of BOOST_PP_REPEAT.

Thanks!

Comment: The solution is to enclose (4,5) in nested parentheses, but I can't get the Boost macro for removing those parentheses because the boost.org DNS entry isn't propagating to me :(

Answer (score 2):

Use [BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/tuple_elem.html):

```
#define TEMPLATE (z, n, data) use_first(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, data)); use_second(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, data));
#define YOUR_MACRO(n, arg1, arg2) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(5, TEMPLATE, (arg1, arg2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the argument list a distinct argument with nested parentheses:

```
BOOST_PP_REPEAT (5, TEMPLATE_2ARG, (4, 5))
```

Then strip the extra parens from inside `TEMPLATE_2ARG`.

```
#define STRIP_PARENS( ... ) __VA_ARGS__

#define TEMPLATE_2ARG( I, ARGS ) TEMPLATE( I, STRIP_PARENS ARGS )
#define TEMPLATE( I, X, Y ) whatever
```